# update an item in a nested array inside a polymer component

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, custom-element

I have a nested repeating template, something like:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{a}}" index-as="a_idx">
    <tr>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.b}}" index-as="b_idx">
            <td>
                <div on-tap="handler" data-a-index="{{a_idx}}" data-b-index="{{b_idx}}">{{item}}</div>
            </td>
        </template>
    </tr>
</template>
```

in my event handler i have something like:

```
    function handler(e) {
        const aIdx = e.target.dataAIndex;
        const bIdx = e.target.dataBIndex;
        const path = `a.${aIdx}.b.${bIdx}`;
        this.set(path, 1234);
    }
```

I was hoping i could set the particular cell to 1234 (or whatever) but what i see is the correct row being updated, but always the first cell. The `path` variable does look like it's being set correctly

Comment: There's an easy way to find out if the `path` variable is being set correctly: `console.log(path)`.

Comment: @Jordan so the path is fine. i get `a.1.b.1` or `a.2.b.4` as i would expect. i just don't see the component updating

Comment: @Michael Dickens, did you find answer to this? I am facing similar problem.

Comment: I never did. Ended up giving up with polymer which was a shame...